# Problems implementing filter method to filter ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, android

I have app that uses a listview to display all the audio files in a folder.  This is working successfully! I am now attempting to add an method to filter the ArrayList, to only show songs that match a String entered by the user.  Unfortunately I am getting a message "cannot resolve method toLowerCase (java.util.Locale)".

I am also looking at other StackOverFlow posts on filtering ArrayLists, but those instances are different enough that my semi-beginner brain is confused on how to apply those answers to my code.

Here is the entire SongsManager.java file  (filter method is at the end):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

public class SongsManager {

    private HashMap<String, String> song;
    private String songString;

    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = "/storage/extSdCard/music";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Constructors
    public SongsManager(String song){
        this.songString = songString;
    }

    public SongsManager(){
    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
     * and store the details in ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs playlist_item array
        return songsList;
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return this.songString;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3") || name.endsWith(".wma"));
        }
    }

  // Filter Class
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filter(String searchString) {
    searchString = searchString.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

    songsList.clear();
    songsList = getPlayList();

    //searchString is empty, so show all songs in results
    if (searchString.length() == 0) {

        if (filteredSongsList != null){
            filteredSongsList.clear();
        }
        filteredSongsList = songsList;
    }

    //only return songs that match the search string
    else {

        if (filteredSongsList != null){
            filteredSongsList.clear();
        }

        for (HashMap<String, String> song : songsList) {
            if (song != null) {
                String songTitle = song.get("songTitle");
                if (songTitle.toLowerCase().contains(searchString)) {
                    filteredSongsList.add(song);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return filteredSongsList;
}
```

Comment: your problem is in the `for (song : songsList)` loop ?

Comment: you cannot do song.toLowerCase because toLowerCase is function in String.class not HashMap.class  .

Comment: @snaikar Since it is song variable is of HashMap class, it looks like I can use the containsKey method.  So that is a good start, but I would still like to make the search case-insensitive.

Comment: Android Studio is also expecting a semicolon at the end of the line
 for (songs : songsList) {

Not sure why

Comment: Ok it looks like I need to specify the datatype for the variable song inside the for loop line.

Comment: I have updated the filter method, still getting error "semicolon expected" on the first line of the for loop

Comment: I have solved the error "cannot resolve method toLowerCase (java.util.Locale)", but when the HashMap is not filtered / nothing happens when I attempt to search.  Perhaps I should post a new question if I can't figure that out, since that is a new problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution: Retrieved songTitle String from HashMap, and applied toLowerCase method to the songTitle String:

```
// Filter Class
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> filter(String searchString) {
        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

    songsList.clear();
    songsList = getPlayList();

    //searchString is empty, so show all songs in results
    if (searchString.length() == 0) {

        if (filteredSongsList != null){
            filteredSongsList.clear();
        }
        filteredSongsList = songsList;
    }

    //only return songs that match the search string
    else {

        if (filteredSongsList != null){
            filteredSongsList.clear();
        }

        for (HashMap<String, String> song : songsList) {
            if (song != null) {
                String songTitle = song.get("songTitle");
                if (songTitle.toLowerCase().contains(searchString)) {
                    filteredSongsList.add(song);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return filteredSongsList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
for (song : songsList)
```

to this:
**[EDIT]**

```
for (HashMap<String, String s : songsList)
```

Comment: Hashmap datatype is required rather than a String, I think I am close to having this solved, but we'll see